# mvc3 Areas - RenderPartial erroring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My RenderPartial is error-ing with

```
    CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 
`'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' 
has some invalid arguments`
```

`/Areas/Admin/News/View.cshtml` has this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Admin/Asset/Views/ViewAsset.cshtml")
```

The above view only says `Hello` atm.

The Asset Controller does not have a controller method for `ViewAsset` as I did not think i need one.

Where am I going wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Asset/ViewAsset.cshtml");
```

Path was issue! Could not see the forest for the trees. Sorry readers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
@Html.Partial("ViewAsset");
```

Comment: Tried just now. `ViewAsset`, `~/Areas/Admin/Asset/Views/ViewAsset`

Comment: Also, `~/Admin/Asset/Views/ViewAsset.cshtml`, `~/Admin/Asset/Views/ViewAsset`